# How to fix 'child_process' and 'fs' dependencies for the module nodeJS 'googleauth.js' used for 'google-cloud/translate'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, google-translate

I want to use the module nodejs '@google-cloud/translate' but some dependencies where not found.

Same problem on windows 10 and ubuntu. I m using nuxtjs : ^2.5.1

Thanks for help me.

I tried to install the package with the documentation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/translate

const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate')

ERROR  Failed to compile with 8 errors
These dependencies were not found:
* child_process in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js

- fs in ./node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js, ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js and 5 others

To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hi, I found a solution many time ago but don't remember. sorry i just saw your answer now

Comment: Is it like resolving some other compilation error on your application @BaptisteCoulon ?

Comment: Were you using an express template? @BaptisteCoulon

Comment: yes, i m using express for call some functions