# Missing dependencies detailed debug information nuxt.js compilation error

Tags: npm, dependency-injection, nuxt.js, node-modules, dependency-management

I am seeing dependencies error similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558281/how-to-fix-child-process-and-fs-dependencies-for-the-module-nodejs-googleau) on my nuxt 2.14.4 app.

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 57 errors

These dependencies were not found:     
* child_process in ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js, ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/testbinary.js and 5 others
* fs in ./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js, ./node_modules/clone-stats/index.js and 48 others
```

1. Installing-re-installing "child_process" and "fs" does not solve the problem. Clearly this is triggered by something else.
2. Unable to locate the source of error as the compilation error does not surface up on the logs. Tried a couple of things to expand the dependencies errors. "--loglevel verbose" and "nuxt-log". But the log does not expand the depedencies. I would like to see all the missing dependencies (5 more for child_process and 48 more for fs as the logs say) to resolve the compilation errors.
3. Not sure if this is an issue with versioning some other modules. Will be able to figure out from 2.
4. Refreshing / Re-creating node_modules is not helping.

[image: Compilation error from logs screenshot attachment]

Comment: I created a fresh workspace with only the components I need. This time the only change was that I **did not use express template**. I don't see "*dependencies not found*" anymore. It is still looking like a workaround though.

Comment: I got closer to root cause now. It is a compilation error on vuex store. I carefully checked store/ folder on nuxt.