# Dependencies were not found despite existing in package.json

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

EDIT: This question is related to [#56558281](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558281/how-to-fix-child-process-and-fs-dependencies-for-the-module-nodejs-googleau) however it's two years old and hasn't been answered

I'm refactoring a few apps we have and tried moving a block of JS code from one NestJs app into another Nuxt app. After installing the dependencies I get this error:

```sh
These dependencies were not found:                                                                                          friendly-errors 11:04:41
                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 11:04:41
* child_process in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js                                          friendly-errors 11:04:41
* fs in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js, ./node_modules/google-p12-pem/build/src/index.js and 4 others
                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 11:04:41
To install them, you can run: npm install --save child_process fs
```

I tried running `npm install --save child_process fs` without luck

Tried deleting node modules and clearing the cache then reinstalling with no luck

and I tried adding this block [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix) without luck either

```json
"browser":{
"child_process": false
}
```

**Package.json**

```json
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.14.5",
    "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.1-rc.5",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.2.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.0",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.17",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "filestack-js": "^3.16.0",
    "googleapis": "^39.2.0",
    "google-auth-library": "^3.1.2",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.12.2",
    "nuxt-webfontloader": "^1.1.0",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "readline": "^1.3.0",
    "tls": "^0.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "url-slug": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apollo": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.3.45",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/pluralize": "0.0.29",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": ">=0.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.11",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typed-graphqlify": "^2.2.3",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-jest": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "browser":{
    "child_process": false
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `npm install google-auth-library` ? maybe the bundled version (inside `googleapis`) has a conflict

Comment: You don't have google-auth-library on the list. Use this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library

Comment: Also, please check the packages that you do install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs

Comment: @malarres Thanks for the response I tried installing google-auth-library but I still get the same issue

Comment: Do you please have a [repro] of this?